# ASP.NET Telerik control styling with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, telerik

I have a radTextBox with CssClass="mandatory".
In jQuery I have the next thing:

```
$(".mandatory").focusout( function () {
  if($(this).val() == "") $(this).css("border", "1px solid #ff0000");
});
```

The problem is that on focusout, my style is "overwritten" by the classes that the control has by default on different events.
I've also tried in jQuery the next thing:

```
$(".mandatory").focusout( function () {
  if($(this).val() == "") $(this).addClass("mandatoryErr");
});
```

But still nothing, the class is immediately removed after it was added.
So how can I add style to teleriks control using jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to hook into the various styling options you have on the client using the [Client-side API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-radtextbox.html) of the RadTextBox. Here's a snippet that takes essentially your initial code and applies it to the RadTextBox API:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeBorder () {
            var textBox = $find("<%= RadTextBox1.ClientID %>");
            if (textBox.get_value() == "") {
                textBox.get_styles().EnabledStyle[0] += "border-color: #ff0000";
                textBox.updateCssClass();
            }
            else {
                //revert back to old CSS
            }
        }
    </script>

    <telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnBlur="ChangeBorder">
    </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

The important items to get out of this is that we are subscribing to a client-side event of the RadTextBox ([OnBlur](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-onblur.html)). Then we access the RadTextBox client-side object, check if the value is "" or not and then access the styles of the RadTextBox object. There are [several different styles](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-styles.html), but it seems as if you're looking for the EnabledStyle. To directly apply some CSS just use the first element of the style array. Alternatively you can apply a CSSClass:

```
textBox.get_styles().EnabledStyle[1] += " mandatoryErr";
```

Where you will be accessing the second element in the styles array. Here you can have mandatoryErr be (for example):

```
    <style>
    .mandatoryErr
    {
        border-color: #ff0000 !important;
    }
</style>
```

The `!important` tag is just there to increase the specificity of the CSS rule, otherwise it will not be applied (if you're using the built-in styles).

If you are looking for more information on all of this, the linked documentation articles should help. You can also use the Chrome Dev Tools and FireBug to inspect the `textBox` variable above and see what the `_styles` property holds :)

Answer (score 0):

I've done this, and works for me.

```
        function txtRadNum_change(e){
            var mustAddColor = e.get_value() == "";
            e.get_styles().EnabledStyle[0] = getStyle(e.get_styles().EnabledStyle[0], mustAddColor);
            e.get_styles().FocusedStyle[0] = getStyle(e.get_styles().FocusedStyle[0], mustAddColor);
            e.get_styles().HoveredStyle[0] = getStyle(e.get_styles().HoveredStyle[0], mustAddColor);
        }

        function getStyle(originalStyle, mustAddColor){
            var lstStyles = originalStyle.split(';');
            var newEnabledStyle = "";
            $.each(lstStyles, function(idx, style){
                if(style.indexOf("background-color") < 0 && style != ""){
                    newEnabledStyle += style + ";";
                }
            });

            if(mustAddColor){
                newEnabledStyle += "background-color:#FC4C02;"
            }

            return newEnabledStyle;
        }
```

You must override the EnabledStyle, FocusedStyle and HoveredStyle http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/input/client-side-programming/inputstyles-client-object